# There exists no integers a and b for which $21a+30b=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Proof: For the sake of contradiction, there exists integers $a$ and $b$ for which $21a+30b=1$, then,
$$21a+30b=1$$
$$3(7a+10b)=1$$
$3n=1$ for some integer $n$, where $n=7a+10b$.
This suggests there exists an integer $n$ for which $3$ divides $1$. However, when $3$ divides $1$, $\frac{1}{3}$ is produced. $\frac{1}{3}$ is known to be a member of the rationals. This would mean n must also be a rational number to allow $3n=1 \Rightarrow n=1/3$. n known to be an integer, but also a rational number, A contradiction.

Sorry for the formatting, it looks a lot nicer on paper. I would love an honest critique. I feel like I am on the right track, but either my wording or some key idea is missing or not expressed properly. Apologies as I am still learning. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Shouldn't your title be *disprove* that there exist integer $a$ and $b$?. Anyway, you should end after stating that both LHS and RHS are integers, but $3$ divides the LHS whereas $3$ does not divide the RHS. Contradiction.

Comment: yes, thank you, I missed adding "no integers". Okay, so I guess I do not need to show the extra stuff about rational numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine, except for your final statement. "n is known to be an integer, but also a rational number. A contradiction." It is much more clear to say that $n$ is an integer, and $1/3$ is not, a contradiction, since integers are rational numbers.